# Why is most of mission control in Houston?

Tags: nasa, launch-site, mission-control, kennedy-space-center, cape-canaveral

They were already making a mission control at Cape Canaveral, and then decided to move some, but not all, of it to Houston. Why? Wouldn't it make more sense to have the entire mission control in one place (Houston or Cape Canaveral). And, since there was already part of a mission control at the Cape, wouldn't it make more sense to just make all of mission control at the Cape? Also, Cape Canaverl is where most of the rockets are being launched (and, until recently, none were launched in Texas), so doesn't it make sense to be closer to the rockets. In other words, why didn't NASA make main control area in Florida, along with the rockets? Why did NASA pick Texas?

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer now, but maybe someone else can use this information: [Technical reason for moving Mission Control from Cape Canaveral to Houston?](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=24395.0) and [CHAPTER 3: Houston - Texas - U.S.A.](https://historycollection.jsc.nasa.gov/JSCHistoryPortal/history/suddenly_tomorrow/chapters/Chpt3.pdf)

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer to the linked question, KSC was **never** considered as the candidate for Mission Control. At the time, it was was a minor launch control center run from Redstone (now the Marshall Space Flight Center). At the time, the Cape was a lowly populated area with no good nearby colleges. Houston had many nearby good colleges at the time. Also note that NASA has control centers in Maryland (Goddard Space Flight Center and the Applied Physics Laboratory), in California (Jet Propulsion Laboratory and Vandenberg), and elsewhere.